# How MAE loss is optimized with SGD optimizer in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gradient-descent

I wonder how MAE loss is optimized with SGD optimizer? I mean how the derivative of absolute values sum is calculated. Is there used any numerical solution or something else?

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and post your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out that in **sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor** MAE loss is a special case of *'epsilon_insensitive'* loss with *epsilon* equal to 0. And according to [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/linear_model/_sgd_fast.pyx#L309) of this loss we simply apply ****sign(x)**** function to difference of ground truth and predicted values in order to calculate derivative.